# Angular and Web API with Ping Federate using WIF

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, wif, pingfederate

I am using Ping to authenticate users in a Angular/.NET Web API stack, utilizing WIF. WIF works out of the box by just putting in the correct configuration in web.config in a MVC or web Forms application. It intercepts any call to a page/controller requested and if no token available redirects to Ping for authentication.

Q1

In my stack that wont work as the web portion of this application is html/Angular. I could put the Ping configuration into the web api config file and then when angular calls the api, WIF will intercept it and (hopefully) redirect user to ping. But not sure if web api can do a http redirect. Also, pages that probably don't do a api call will load up just fine without authentication...

Q2

Lets say Issue 1 is resolved and user authenticates himself at ping, ping will need to send that assertion to the web api layer and not to html/Angular as it is a POST response. That is fine and web api will check the Claims object to get the user info. After which we will need to redirect the user to go back to the page he was trying to access, which now, app will not know anymore. Also how to achieve http redirection from web api.

Q3

Is there a way for Ping to post to a html/angular page?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Are you using an integration kit of some sort?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the WIF .net Integration. I'm following the steps from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh987037(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: PingFederate can act as a WS-Trust-compatible STS. Your app collects the username/password, and forward them on to PF in a properly formatted WS-Trust Authn message, and you get back a WS-Trust Assertion. You can see WS-Trust configuration for PingFed here: https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf80/index.shtml#adminGuide/concept/wsTrustStsConfiguration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the RESTful nature of APIs, they will not be able to do an HTTP Redirect. Even if they could it would be during an AJAX call and not affect the browser.

Out of the box WIF only supports the following protocols:

- WS-Fed
- WS-Trust
- WS-Security
- WS-SecurityPolicy
- WS-Addressing

I suggest using the OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant Type for the Angular/WebAPI portion.

That being said, the claims-based identity provided by WIF and OAuth are really complimentary. You could write an OAuth extension for WIF similair to the one referenced here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg193416.aspx

This is what I imagine the flow would look like:

1. Angular app requests information from WIF protected API
2. API returns status code 401
3. Angular app performs redirect to Ping OAuth Authorization Endpoint
4. User Authenticates if they do not already have an existing session with the SSO IdP Server
5. Bearer token is returned to the Angular app
6. Bearer token is added to the Authorization header and sent to the API
7. WIF intercepts the request, extracts the Bearer token and calls the Ping OAuth Token Endpoint to validate the token
8. Ping returns a token that has the "Claims" information you are looking for, those claims are then injected into WIF.

Comment: Yeah, i guess i will have to go the looonger way... WIF was so easy. Found a pure angular client side solution here though http://andreareginato.github.io/oauth-ng/

Comment: @Vaibhav your link goes to a 404 now. Can you please update it?